# CertGetCertificateChain - Invalid memory access

Tags: java, jna, cryptoapi

Cross-posting for visibility: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jna-users/qfkoxPwA-r8

I am working on creating a wrapper for the CertGetCertificateChain method in the Crypt32 lib and I would like to get help in resolving an 'Invalid Memory Access' issue that results in a crash.

The signature for the wrapper is:

```
boolean CertGetCertificateChain(Pointer hChainEngine, PCERT_CONTEXT pCertContext, Pointer pTime,
            Pointer hAdditionalStore, CERT_CHAIN_PARA.ByReference pChainPara, int dwFlags, Pointer pvReserved,
            PointerByReference ppChainContext);
```

The structures i am using are:

```
public static class CERT_CHAIN_PARA extends Structure {
    public int cbSize;
    public CERT_USAGE_MATCH RequestedUsage;

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("cbSize", "RequestedUsage");
    }


    public static class ByReference extends CERT_CHAIN_PARA implements Structure.ByReference {}
}


public static class CERT_USAGE_MATCH extends Structure {
    public int dwType;
    public CERT_ENHKEY_USAGE Usage;


    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("dwType", "Usage");
    }


    public static class ByReference extends CERT_USAGE_MATCH implements Structure.ByReference {}
}


public static class CERT_ENHKEY_USAGE extends Structure {
    public int cUsageIdentifier;
    public LPSTR.ByReference rgpszUsageIdentifier;


    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("cUsageIdentifier", "rgpszUsageIdentifier");
    }


    public static class ByReference extends CERT_ENHKEY_USAGE implements Structure.ByReference {}
}
```

There are copies of the ones in the Wincrypt.h header. CERT_CHAIN_PARA has additional members that become active only when a flag is enabled and I have not enabled it in the native code. So, i avoided adding them here.

The calling code is:

```
CERT_CHAIN_PARA.ByReference pChainPara = new CERT_CHAIN_PARA.ByReference();
PointerByReference p = new PointerByReference();


pChainPara.cbSize = pChainPara.size();
pChainPara.RequestedUsage.dwType = WinCrypt.USAGE_MATCH_TYPE_AND;
pChainPara.RequestedUsage.Usage.cUsageIdentifier = 0;
pChainPara.RequestedUsage.Usage.rgpszUsageIdentifier = null;


CertGetCertificateChain(null, pCertContext, null, null, pChainPara, 0, null, p);
```

The crash happens on the call to CertGetCertificateChain. One thing i've noticed it that setting pChainPara to null stops it from throwing the memory access exception and crashing. But i am not sure if this is because the pChainPara structure is corrupt or if setting null forces it to fail early and masks an issue somewhere else. I've checked the sizes of the structure passed in and they match with the sizes in the native code.

Please let me know if i need to provide more information. Once implemented and tested, i'll clean this up and contribute the certificate workflow's wrappers and structures to JNA.

Edit:
I tried adding the additional members in CERT_CHAIN_PARA as given below:

```
    public static class CERT_CHAIN_PARA extends Structure {

        public int cbSize;
        public CERT_USAGE_MATCH RequestedUsage;

        public CERT_USAGE_MATCH RequestedIssuancePolicy;
        public int dwUrlRetrievalTimeout;
        public boolean fCheckRevocationFreshnessTime;
        public int dwRevocationFreshnessTime;
        public FILETIME pftCacheResync;
        public CERT_STRONG_SIGN_PARA.ByReference pStrongSignPara;
        public int dwStrongSignFlags;

        @Override
        protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
            //          return Arrays.asList("cbSize", "RequestedUsage");
            return Arrays.asList("cbSize", "RequestedUsage","RequestedIssuancePolicy","dwUrlRetrievalTimeout","fCheckRevocationFreshnessTime",
                    "dwRevocationFreshnessTime","pftCacheResync","pStrongSignPara","dwStrongSignFlags");
        }

        public static class ByReference extends CERT_CHAIN_PARA implements Structure.ByReference {

        }
    }

    public static class CERT_STRONG_SIGN_SERIALIZED_INFO extends Structure {
        DWORD dwFlags;
        LPWSTR pwszCNGSignHashAlgids;
        LPWSTR pwszCNGPubKeyMinBitLengths;

        @Override
        protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList("dwFlags", "pwszCNGSignHashAlgids", "pwszCNGPubKeyMinBitLengths");
        }

        public static class ByReference extends CERT_STRONG_SIGN_SERIALIZED_INFO implements Structure.ByReference {
        }
    }

    public static class DUMMYUNIONNAME extends Union {
        Pointer pvInfo;
        CERT_STRONG_SIGN_SERIALIZED_INFO.ByReference pSerializedInfo;
        LPSTR pszOID;
    }

    public static class CERT_STRONG_SIGN_PARA extends Structure {
        public int cbSize;
        public int dwInfoChoice;

        public DUMMYUNIONNAME union;

        @Override
        protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList("cbSize", "dwInfoChoice", "union");
        }

        public static class ByReference extends CERT_STRONG_SIGN_PARA implements Structure.ByReference {
        }
    }

    public static class FILETIME extends Structure {

        public int dwLowDateTime;
        public int dwHighDateTime;

        @Override
        protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList("dwLowDateTime", "dwHighDateTime");
        }

        public static class ByReference extends FILETIME implements Structure.ByReference {
        }

        public static class ByValue extends FILETIME implements Structure.ByValue {
        }
    }
}
```

And the calling code was modified to set the rest of the members:

```
pChainPara.RequestedIssuancePolicy.Usage.cUsageIdentifier = 0;
pChainPara.RequestedIssuancePolicy.Usage.rgpszUsageIdentifier = null;

pChainPara.dwUrlRetrievalTimeout = 0;
pChainPara.fCheckRevocationFreshnessTime = false;
pChainPara.dwRevocationFreshnessTime = 0;
pChainPara.pftCacheResync.dwHighDateTime = 0;
pChainPara.pftCacheResync.dwLowDateTime = 0;

pChainPara.pStrongSignPara = null;
```

But I still get the failure as mentioned above.

Edit2:

```
PCERT_CONTEXT context = CryptUIDlgSelectCertificateFromStore(store, hwnd,
                "", "", 2, 0, null);

    public static class CERT_CONTEXT extends Structure {

        public int dwCertEncodingType;
        public Pointer pbCertEncoded;
        public int cbCertEncoded;
        public Pointer pCertInfo;
        public Pointer hCertStore;

        @Override
        protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList("dwCertEncodingType", "pbCertEncoded", "cbCertEncoded", "pCertInfo", "hCertStore");
        }

        public static class ByReference extends CERT_CONTEXT implements Structure.ByReference {
        }
    }

    public static class PCERT_CONTEXT extends Structure {

        public CERT_CONTEXT.ByReference certContext;

        @Override
        protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList("certContext");
        }

        public static class ByReference extends PCERT_CONTEXT implements Structure.ByReference {
        }

        public static class ByValue extends PCERT_CONTEXT implements Structure.ByValue {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Structures passed as parameters by default are treated as `struct *`, so any `ByReference` tags there are superfluous.   If the sizes match, then the problem is more likely in one of the pointer types.

Comment: Thanks. That saves me some time from trying it out with and without 'ByReference'.

Comment: Please show definition and construction of `pCertContext`.

Comment: Done. I think the context is a valid one as i've tried a 'CryptSignMessage' with it and that worked.

Comment: IIUC, in native code `PCERT_CONTEXT` is a typedef to `CERT_CONTEXT *`.  Your Java definition will in effect make it `CERT_CONTEXT **`, at least w/r/t passing it as a parameter.  If you need native `CERT_CONTEXT *`, use Java `CERT_CONTEXT` as you've defined.

Comment: I tried using just CERT_CONTEXT in a simplified [example](https://github.com/rosh89/test-cert-jna) and that failed too.

Comment: Could you add your last comment on this thread as the answer. Playing around with removing PCERT_CONTEXT and ByReference fixed the issue for me. It similar to the answer i got from my post in the jna users group too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite possible that you need to define the remainder of the `CERT_CHAIN_PARA` structure, since its expected size depends on a compile-time variable (independent of what you might supply in `cbSize`).

> Note  This member can be used only if CERT_CHAIN_PARA_HAS_EXTRA_FIELDS
>   is defined by using the #define directive before including Wincrypt.h.
>   If this value is defined, the application must zero all unused fields.

**UPDATE**

`PCERT_CONTEXT` is a typedef to `CERT_CONTEXT *`. Your Java definition will in effect make it `CERT_CONTEXT **`, at least w/r/t passing it as a parameter. If you need native `CERT_CONTEXT *`, use Java `CERT_CONTEXT` as the parameter type.  Embedding a pointer field within a struct effectively gives the callee the *address* of the value you wish to pass, rather than the pointer value you really want to pass.

In general you should omit the `<Structure>.ByReference` notation *unless* you are defining a structure field that needs to be of type `struct *`.

Comment: I had compared it with the native implementation without the additional variables, as mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382042(v=vs.85).aspx), and i got the same sizes.

I also tried your suggestion and i am still getting the issue. I'll add the new structure definitions and the callign code as part of the original post for better formatting.